# Different results from cs2cs and gdaltransform

Tags: gdal, proj

I expected to get the same result when performing a transformation using cs2cs and gdaltransform. However, the results differ:

`echo "53.70015N 9.12875E" | cs2cs EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857
1016207.80      7113571.58 0.00`

`echo "53.70015N 9.12875E" | gdaltransform -rpc -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857
5977873.35352241 1020534.697294 0`

`cs2cs -v
Rel. 6.2.1, November 1st, 2019`

Gdal version is 3.0.2 using the same Proj4 lib.

Maybe I have completely misunderstood the two programs. When I use the results from cs2cs as corners for gdal_translate, I get the expected results, however:
`wget http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/8/134/82.png
gdal_translate -of PNG -outsize 256 0 -projwin 939825 7200381 1095810 7045677 -projwin_srs EPSG:3857 /usr/local/src/gdal-3.0.2/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml hemmoor_82.png`

Will produce the same output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the difference:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
53.70015N 9.12875E
5977873.35352241 1020534.697294 0
9.12875 53.70015
1016207.8015791 7113571.58479506 0
```

With the default settings gdaltransform seems to take the arguments in longitude-latitude or easting-northing order.